# how to remove duplicate characters in sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

**Before：**

```
我是中国人来自中国，I am Chinese people from China
```

**After：**

```
我是中国人来自，IamChinespolfr
```

how to remove duplicate characters in sublime ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A a one-liner for the ST console `` ctrl+` ``:

```py
import collections; content="".join(collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys(view.substr(sublime.Region(0, view.size())))); view.run_command("select_all"); view.run_command("insert", {"characters": content})
```

If you want to write a plugin press `Tools >>> New Plugin...` and write:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin
from collections import OrderedDict


class RemoveDuplicateCharactersCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def remove_chars(self, edit, region):
        view = self.view
        content = "".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(view.substr(region)))
        view.replace(edit, region, content)

    def run(self, edit):
        view = self.view
        all_sel_empty = True
        for sel in view.sel():
            if sel.empty():
                continue
            all_sel_empty = False
            self.remove_chars(edit, sel)
        if all_sel_empty:
            self.remove_chars(edit, sublime.Region(0, view.size()))
```

And create a keybinding in `Keybindings - User`:

```js
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+alt+shift+r"],
    "command": "remove_duplicate_characters",
},
```

Afterwards you can just select a text and press `ctrl+alt+shift+r` and the duplicated characters will be removed. If you don't have a selection, it will be applied for the whole view.

Comment: nice solution, less repetitious manual work than my non-plugin/python based answer :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the `Find` menu
2. Select `Replace...`
3. Ensure the `Regular expression` mode is enabled
4. In `Find What:`, type `(.)(.*?)\1`
5. In `Replace With:`, type `$1$2`
6. Click `Replace All`
7. Repeat until there are no more matches/duplicate characters